Derivative Approximation from Trigometric Interpolation vs Polynomial Interpolation
In the classical finite difference method one takes the derivatives of interpolating polynomials and derives the finite difference coefficients from those. The polynomial degree and consistency can be increased by making it interpolate more and more points on the grid.
Another approach is to fit trigonometric interpolating polynomials and take the derivatives of those (what is termed a spectral or Fourier approach).
My question is whether I get the same finite difference stencils as the ones from the trigonometric approach if I make the polynomials interpolate every point on the grid. I am specifically interested in the second derivative $d_{xx}$, and the boundary conditions can be assumed periodic (since any others can be reduced to those through reflection/anti-reflection).
In the case when I take the simplest approximation $d_{xx}u_j \approx \frac{u_{j-1} - 2 u_j + u_{j+1}}{h^2}$ with periodic BCs the resulting matrix is diagonalized by the DFT and the eigenvalues are $-\frac{4}{h^2}\sin^2(\pi j/n)$, while for the trigonometric approach those are $-\frac{4}{h^2} \pi^2 j^2/n^2$, i.e., the finite difference eigenvalues can be seen as a low-frequency approximation that agrees with the trigonometric case for $j$ close to $0$.
It's clear that the continuous interpolating polynomials and their trigonometric counterparts cannot agree  everywhere. The question is, however,  whether the resulting stencils agree provided the same number of interpolation points are taken in the classical approach. At first glance I would say that this is unlikely, and probably the best that can be done is comparing how close those are. But maybe someone is aware of a reference that discusses this in details.
For simplicity you can assume that a regular grid is given with $n=2k+1$ points (where the first and last point are interpreted as the same maybe?), so the stencil for $d_{xx}$ on it can be derived at the central point and cover the whole grid. Since the BCs are periodic all other stencils are just shifted copies of it. The Fourier case is explicitly known through the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Basically would the FD matrix's eigenvalues agree or be close to the Fourier ones?
Additionally the $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ stencil with explicit Euler and step $\tau <\frac{h^2}{2}$ does not increase the maximum or decrease the minimum, but higher order stencils (including the Fourier approach) do not fulfill this property. Is there a way to rectify this?

I am not sure what you actually want to compare. Instead of thinking in terms of stencils (the poor man's approach) you should think in terms of basis functions and collocation. Moreover, if you want to compare the spectral stencils (spanning the whole grid) you also need to consider the one-sided stencils. All stencils (local and global) can be easily derived via generalized Vandermonde matrices, with the formula $\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{V}' \mathbf{V}^{-1}$. Or are you actually looking to compare local polynomial stencils with the global Fourier ones?

@ConvexHull The functions are classical polynomials vs trigonometric polynomials. Both interpolate the data points, and when differentiated produce the stencil. I agree that theoretically it is important to know where my stencils arose from, but in practice I work with the stencils. I do not understand why I would need one-sided stencils: as mentioned I am considering periodic boundary conditions so all stencils are shifted versions of each other - the matrix is circulant and diagonalized by the DFT. I know how the stencils are derived, I am asking about a reference that compares the two.

I missed that you specifically want to compare the stencils on a periodic grid, where you one-sided stencils are nonsense. I currently have no literature, except the ones off Canuto et al. or Boyd et al..
For small number of points one can directly see that they differ, as trigonometric functions are inherently infinitely differentiable, which is not the case for general polynomials. I assume, that this is also the case in general.

I tried to derive it myself and I think it turned out fine. Basically the classical polynomials stencils' eigenvalues agree with the Fourier stencils' eigenvalues with an error of $O((jh)^{2r+2})$, where $h=1/n$ is the distance between nodes, and $0\leq j \leq n/2$ is the frequency. If $n/2<j\leq n-1$ then it is $O(((n-j)h)^{2r+2})$. So the higher the order of consistency $2r$, the lower the distance $h=1/n$, and the lower the frequency $j$, the closer those are. Since the highest frequency is $j=n/2$ for it one has a convergence of $O(2^{-2r-2})$. Where $r$ can also be at most $n/2-1$, so $O(2^{-n})$ in the best case.

Trigonometric Interpolation
The trigonometric interpolating polynomial $u$ such that $u(k/n) = v_k$ for $k \in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ can be written (for $n$ even, the odd case is analogous with the cosine term dropped) as:
$$u_v(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{n/2-1} \hat{v}_j \exp\left(i\cdot 2\pi j\cdot t\right) + \hat{v}_{n/2}\cos\left(2\pi \cdot \frac{n}{2}\cdot t\right) +  \sum_{j=n/2+1}^{n-1} \hat{v}_j \exp\left(-i\cdot 2\pi (n-j)\cdot t\right),$$
where $\hat{v}$ is the discrete Fourier transform of $v$. Taking the second derivative of $u$ one gets $d_{xx}u_v(t) = u_{w}(t)$ where $\hat{w}_j = -(2\pi j)^2\cdot\hat{v}_j$ for $0\leq j \leq n/2$, and $\hat{w}_j = -(2\pi (n-j))^2\cdot\hat{v}_j$ for $n/2+1\leq j \leq n-1$. That is, we can apply the second derivative by multiplying $\hat{v}$ elementwise with the above mentioned coefficients vector.

Classical Polynomial Interpolation Stencils
Now consider the classical finite difference approach. A central difference for $d_{xx}$ with consistency $O(h^{2r})$ ($h=1/n$) can be computed by taking a polynomial of degree $2r$ that interpolates at the points $x_{-r},\ldots, x_{-1}, x_0, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{r}$ and taking its second derivative. This yields the stencil
$$a = \begin{bmatrix} a_{-r} & \ldots & a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1 & \ldots & a_r \end{bmatrix},$$
that satisfies the system resulting from the Taylor expansion of $(a\cdot u_{k-r,\ldots,k+r})$, with the requirement that all coefficients are zero in front of $d_x^{(l)}u(k/n)$ terms for $l\in\{0,\ldots, 2r\}\setminus \{2\}$, and the term in front of $d_{xx}$ is $1$, i.e., $d_{xx} u(k/n) = (a\cdot u_{k-r,\ldots,k+r}) + O(h^{2r})$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \ldots & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
-r & \ldots & -1 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & r \\
(-r)^2 & \ldots & (-1)^2 & 0 & 1^2 & \ldots & r^2 \\
(-r)^3 & \ldots & (-1)^3 & 0 & 1^3 & \ldots & r^3 \\
\vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
(-r)^{2r} & \ldots & (-1)^{2r} & 0 & 1^{2r} & \ldots & r^{2r}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{-r} \\ \vdots \\ a_{-1} \\ a_0 \\ a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_r \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{2!}{h^2} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.\tag{1}$$
Also note that this stencil is symmetric:
$$a_{-k} = a_{k}.\tag{*}$$
The matrix $A$ corresponding to $d_{xx}$ with periodic boundary conditions can be formed by producing the circulant matrix from the above stencil.

Eigenvalues of $A$
Since the matrix is circulant, its eigenvalues can be computed by multiplying with the DFT basis vectors $f_0,\ldots,f_{n-1}$ (i.e. those are its eigenvectors):
$$Af_j = \lambda_j f_j \implies (Af_j)_j = \lambda_j f_{jj} \iff 
\sum_{k=-r}^r a_k \exp\left(i\cdot \frac{2\pi j}{n}\cdot (j+k)\right) = \lambda_j \exp\left(i\cdot \frac{2\pi j}{n}\cdot j\right).$$
Setting $\theta_j = \frac{2\pi j}{n}$ for $0\leq j \leq n/2$ and $\theta_j = -\frac{2\pi (n-j)}{n}$ for $n/2<j\leq n-1$ we have:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-r}^r a_k \exp\left(i\cdot\theta_j\cdot (j+k)\right) &= \lambda_j \exp\left(i\cdot\theta_j\cdot j\right) \\
a_0\exp\left(i\cdot\theta_j\cdot j\right) + \sum_{k=1}^r 2a_k \exp(i\cdot\theta_j \cdot j)\frac{\exp(i\cdot\theta_j\cdot k)+\exp(-i\cdot\theta_j\cdot k)}{2} &= \lambda_j \exp\left(i\cdot\theta_j\cdot j\right) \\
a_0 + 2\sum_{k=1}^r a_k \cos(\theta_j\cdot k) &= \lambda_j \\
\sum_{k=-r}^r a_k \cos(\theta_j\cdot k) &= \lambda_j \\
\sum_{k=-r}^r a_k \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^l\frac{\theta_j^{2l}k^{2l}}{(2l)!} &= \lambda_j \\
\sum_{l=0}^{r}(-1)^l\frac{\theta_j^{2l}}{(2l)!}\sum_{k=-r}^r a_k k^{2l} + 
\sum_{l=r+1}^{\infty}(-1)^l \frac{\theta_j^{2l}}{(2l)!}\sum_{k=-r}^r a_k k^{2l} &= \lambda_j
 \\
-\frac{\theta_j^2}{h^2} + O((jh)^{2r+2}) &= \lambda_j \\
-(2\pi j)^2 + O((jh)^{2r+2}) &= \lambda_j
\end{align}
In step two I used the symmetry of the stencil $(*)$ ($a_{-k} = a_k$). In step seven I used that the stencil coefficients solve the system in $(1)$.
So these eigenvalues are the Fourier ones plus some error term $O((jh)^{2r+2})$. The higher the consistency order $2r$, the lower the distance $h=1/n$, and the lower the frequency $j$, the closer the eigenvalues become.

General Case for $d_{xx}^s$ (Still Central Differences Though)
From the trigonometric interpolation one gets $(-1)^s(2\pi j)^{2s}$ for $0\leq j \leq n/2$, and $(-1)^s(2\pi j)^{2s}$ for $n/2+1\leq j \leq n-1$. From the classical interpolation we again have $\lambda_j = (-1)^s(2\pi j)^{2s} + O((jh)^{2r+2})$.
I believe that a similar result can be derived for the other boundary conditions by considering all the DCTs and DSTs, since they give all possible combinations of boundary conditions (at least for $d_{xx}$). But as far as I know those cannot handle for example Dirichlet conditions $u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$ and $\partial_n u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ for the fourth derivative $d_{xxxx}$. Though I suppose a similar result should still hold regarding the eigenvalues.

Might it be worthwhile to extend the comparison to non-circulant matrices that arise with non-equidistant points?

@ConvexHull The non-circulant cases are handled with the various types of the DCT and DST. I don't think that this changes much since differentiating twice a cosine or a sine function just pops out its negated argument squared as for the DFT setting. So I think the argument needs to be modified only minimally in order to handle Dirichlet and Neumann conditions. As for non-equidistant points you would need a non-equidistant trigonometric and classical interpolants plus the non-uniform discrete Fourier transform. That seems like quite a bit more work. Albeit maybe a remapping can be considered.

@ConvexHull I haven't proven it, but my guess is that for the non-equidistant case you could just replace $h$ with $h_{\max}$ as a loose estimate and more or less the same result should hold. Here $h_{\max}$ is the largest distance between consecutive nodes. I expect that the takeaway is the same though - the classical finite differences are a low frequency approximation of the trigonometric discrete derivatives. As you increase the consistency order (i.e. the degree of the interpolating polynomials) and as you decrease $h_{\max}$ you should get closer and closer to the trigonometric case.

@ConvexHull I thought a bit more on the non-equidistant case. Even for a 3-point stencil the latter results in a generic tridiagonal symmetric matrix, and there are no closed form solutions for its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, you just have a three term recurrence. If there were a closed form solution you would have a closed form solution for any symmetric matrix, since any symmetric matrix is similar to a tridiagonal one. So one could potentially study this only numerically wrt the eigenvalues. You can of course compare the resulting stencils instead, but that's a different problem.

@ConvexHull As for the trigonometric interpolation - the latter relies on $u(t) = \sum_j w_j \exp(2\pi i j t)$ and $u(t_k) = v_k$.  But $F_{kj} = \exp(2\pi i j t_k)$ is not necessarily unitary anymore, so $w = F^{-1}v$ is not given through the NUDFT as far as I can tell. You can still compute the eigenvalues of the second derivative as before. Also it's not $F$ that diagonalizes the classical finite differences on an irregular grid anymore, so you potentially have matrices with different eigenvectors between classical and trig, i.e., the prev analysis breaks.

That sounds interesting, I always find it very useful and interesting to generalize things to get a clearer understanding, thanks for your effort so far.

@ConvexHull The above just says that the approach I used here won't work by relating the eigenvalues since the eigenvectors do not have to agree. I still believe that a bound should be possible with $O(h_{\max}^p)$ showing up somewhere. E.g. maybe if one constructs a bound for the Frobenius norm. I don't have any ideas at the moment as to the specific mathematical tools required, however. And I probably won't pursue this much further as I mostly cared about the regular grid case, since there you have a closed form solution for the eigendecomposition, which is practically relevant.
